# Android: Util class static method with background thread (async task)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-lifecycle

I have utility class with static methods. Assuming that these methods can fire background task, something like below:

```
class ExampleAsyncUtil {
    public static void doSomeAsyncJob() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> () {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground (Void... params) {
                //do heavy job here ...
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

if then i call the util class method inside activity which then becomes destroyed:

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ExampleAsyncUtil.doSomeAsyncJob();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        //should i stop async task in util on destroy ?

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Does it do any harm? (assuming that the background thread does not keep any refrence to activity which called the utility method)

Comment: Is there a valid reason to create AsyncTask without a `Context`? There is not so much you can do that matters to the user. Example downside: if user exits your Activity, whole process is first to be killed - it matters if you want your task to finish the job. I might elaborate if you provide your reasons for that construct.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, and yes, it could be thread instead in this case. But why do associate `AsyncTask` with `Context` from docs it seems to be just a class that helps common frequent thread handling scenario.

Comment: You don't have to associate it with Context. From your other comment, it looks like you need the thread to finish its job - in that case use a `Service` - it is much less likely to be killed and you get tools to handle the killings. If you don't need thread to finish its job, don't eat user's battery and stop it :)

Comment: Service needs a lot of coding - people are lazy, i am not exceptional in that case ;). The util class would havemany many methods for short async operations in bg thread some of them with not serializable arguments. Nound service, binding to service monitoring if it is not disconnected and so on ... - feels like pain in the ass. I was looking fo "easy" solution ;)

Comment: Well, that's fine if you can afford your bg tasks being killed at any time.  If your updates are idempotent, transactional (or negligible?), there seem to be no stoppers to your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should cancel the AsyncTask from your UI. You can leak the AsyncTask otherwise (talking from experience).  And, who knows, maybe even block another from being started on the same thread: they keep changing the implementation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Or, contrary, multiple onCreate() could create duplicate "zombie" AsyncTask's. Anyway, it's not an intended use of AsyncTask: they are supposed to be short-lived and properly controlled.  So, there seems to be no real gain in that static business.

I think you should either start a Service and spawn a tread from it or just use AsyncTask traditionally, within the life cycle of your Activity.

There is a good tutorial on asynchronous handling here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but I understand services and async tasks, as well as read many of lars' tutorials long ago ;). I intentionally gave the example where this task does not store any reference to activities or its resources (so it is not zombie as it is not interested in its callee activity). As this is utility method, independents calls are just the right scenario. ...

Comment: ... I know the issues of implementation change with async tasks (pool or queue depending of system version) but it is not issue of that question. The clue of the question is if the starting a new thread in static method is somehow bound to acivity which called the static method, and it seems that it isn't - so after clarifing what i meant in question i think i found the answer :).

Comment: And by the way the lars vogel's tutorial example `ThreadsLifecycleActivity` seems to be leaky. This tutorial is quite old (2 years now) so it can be taken for "first investigations" not "noble pattern" ;)

Comment: Anyway, can we rule out ALL possible complications?  Somehow, AcyncTask seems to have some internal notion of UI thread vs. background thread, right?  So, is it really bulletproof; no side effects can be buried there in current or future versions of the OS?  Not sure.  To me it still looks like programming by coincidence.

Comment: Ok forget async task - if there were Thread instead of AsyncTak, it should then finish successfully even after activity has been destroyed before. I wanted to ensure If I am right in that :).

Comment: Should it be a daemon thread then?  Otherwise, what terminates first - the JVM or the thread - may still be a matter of coincidence.